# Office365 Calendar Recurring Event API - get only changes, updated & deleted

Tags: php, symfony, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, api-platform.com

I have implemented Recurring Event with google api and I want to integrate office 365 calendar recurring as well, I can read the event from office 365 calendar api, but when I want to take only changed instances I can not find any api endpoint that return only changes like google does.

I'm using endpoints like:

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/me/calendars/{calendarId}/calendarview](https://graph.microsoft.com/me/calendars/%7BcalendarId%7D/calendarview)

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/me/calendars/%7BcalendarId%7D/events)

Endpoint 'events' return main recurring event, this is what I'm using to read the main event, and works fine.

Endpoint 'calendarView' returns all events calculated for recurring event, if is daily without end, it will return 365 events for whole year if you query that way.

The problem is I can't read updated or deleted instances for this recurring event. I tried delta/feed endpoint but returns everything without any status or information for updated or deleted instances/occurrences.

Does anyone have found any solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not supported currently. Being said that, consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so that it could be considered for future implementation.